# C# 7 switch case with null checks

Tags: c#, switch-statement, pattern-matching, c#-7.0, null-string

C#7 introduces a new feature called *patterns*, which you can use with Is-Expression or Switch cases like this:

```
string str = null; 
switch(str){
    case string x:
        Console.WriteLine("string " + x);
        break;
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("default");
        break;
}
```

and you would expect that it will goes inside case #1, as it is the same type, but it didn't.

Comment: "as it is the same type" - not really. If you do `object o = str; bool isString = o is string;` then `isString` will be false...

Comment: yes, correct, a null string doesn't refer to System.String object

Comment: @JonSkeet, I would appreciate if you see my answer below, and review it.

Comment: Patrick's answer is definitely a better one IMO.

Answer (score 16):

Despite what you might think, `string x = null` actually isn't a string at all. It is 'nothing', assigned to a variable of type string.

The check in your switch is basically the same as `null is string` which is `false` for a long time already. This is a common issue when evaluating types with generics, but it has its plus sides too.

Under the hood, `is` uses `as`, with a null check. So that is why it can't return true. You could say the logic for the `is` operator is as follows:

```
is = (null as string) != null
```

Comment: Thanks @patrick-hofman And the concept of creating a null case if I didn't  provide one. is this correct?

Comment: Yes. That is the only option.

Answer (score 0):

actually they are not because of the null on string.

the idea is that *switch* cases with patterns in c#7 adds another case for Null checking while evaluating the cases, and if you didn't add your Null case check, it will go to *default* case, so it is better to add a null case while using this new feature, or leave it to default if you know what default will do.

Hope it helps!

Comment: No, that is not the idea behind it. The thing is just how .NET works under the hood. See my answer which explains how this pattern is implemented.