# switch with var/null strange behavior

Tags: c#, null, switch-statement, var, c#-7.0

Given the following code:

```
string someString = null;
switch (someString)
{
    case string s:
        Console.WriteLine("string s");
        break;
    case var o:
        Console.WriteLine("var o");
        break;
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("default");
        break;
}
```

Why is the switch statement matching on `case var o`?

It is my understanding that `case string s` does not match when `s == null` because (effectively) `(null as string) != null` evaluates to false. IntelliSense on VS Code tells me that `o` is a `string` as well. Any thoughts?

---

Similiar to: [C# 7 switch case with null checks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42950833/c-sharp-7-switch-case-with-null-checks)

Comment: Confirmed. I love this question, ***especially*** with the observation that `o` is `string` (confirmed with generics - i.e. `Foo(o)` where `Foo<T>(T template) => typeof(T).Name`) - it is a very interesting case where `string x` behaves differently than `var x` even when `x` is typed (by the compiler) as `string`

Comment: The default case is dead code. Believe we should be issuing a warning there. Checking.

Comment: @JaredPar I get no warnings locally. But to me it is odd that `case string foo` is a miss yet `case var foo` is a hit when `foo` is resolved as `string`. That's ... very subtle

Comment: Sorry comment was confusing.  Agree there is no warning. Checking to see if indeed we should be issuing one here.

Comment: It is odd `var` behavior should be different than `string`.

Comment: It is odd to me that the C# designers decided to allow `var` in this context at all. That sure seems like the kind of thing I'd find in C++, not in a language purported to lead the programmer "into the pit of success". Here, `var` is both ambiguous and useless, things that C# design typically seems to strive to avoid.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I wouldn't say useless; the inbound expression to the `switch` could be unpronounceable - anonymous types, etc; and it isn't *ambiguous* - the compiler clearly knows the type; it is just confusing (to me at least) that the `null` rules are so different!

Comment: @Marc: okay, I'll go along with the anonymous type scenario. But I still find the behavior confusing, non-unintuitive, and not at all C#-like. I mean, this is the language where, while it's true we had to live with problem-prone behavior with captured `foreach` variables, they _did_ eventually fix that. Inconsistency in treatment of `null` values here seems like a similar pitfall that would normally have been avoided.

Comment: @PeterDuniho fun fact - we once looked up the definite assignment formal rules from the C# 1.2 specification, and the illustrative expansion code had the variable declaration *inside* the block (where it is now); it only moved *outside* in 2.0, then back inside again when the capture problem was obvious.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Inside a pattern matching `switch` statement using a `case` for an explicit type is asking if the value in question is of that specific type, or a derived type.  It's the exact equivalent of `is`

```
switch (someString) {
  case string s:
}
if (someString is string)
```

The value `null` does not have a type and hence does not satisfy either of the above conditions.  The static type of `someString` doesn't come into play in either example.

The `var` type though in pattern matching acts as a wild card and will match any value including `null`.

The `default` case here is dead code.  The `case var o` will match any value, null or non-null.  A non-default case always wins over a default one hence `default` will never be hit.  If you look at the IL you'll see it's not even emitted.

At a glance it may seem odd that this compiles without any warning (definitely threw me off).  But this is matching with C# behavior that goes back to 1.0.  The compiler allows `default` cases even when it can trivially prove that it will never be hit.  Consider as an example the following:

```
bool b = ...;
switch (b) {
  case true: ...
  case false: ...
  default: ...
}
```

Here `default` will never be hit (even for `bool` that have a value that isn't 1 or 0).  Yet C# has allowed this since 1.0 without warning.  Pattern matching is just falling in line with this behavior here.

Comment: The real issue though is that the compiler "shows" `var` to be of type `string` when it's really not (honestly not sure what the type should be admittedly)

Comment: @shmuelie the type of `var` in the example is calculated to be `string`.

Comment: in the example though `var` would match an `Int32` just as well, no?

Comment: _"the type of var in the example is calculated to be string"_ -- then it's not really a wildcard, is it? Your answer seems very "hand-wavy" to me, with a bit of contortion to try to force an explanation when the behavior itself is logically inconsistent. (As I noted above, I'm surprised you allow `var` at all in this context...it doesn't seem useful, or at least not enough to justify the potential for confusion and non-intuitive behavior.)

Comment: @shmuelie not given the inbound expression to the `switch`

Comment: After staring at this for a while I think I get it: `var` is of type `string` because var type resolution checks the type of `someString`. However, the rules of pattern matching result in the resolved type of `var` being moot because the var case has no other parts to the pattern (as soon as you add a `when` to the var case it isn't a wild anymore).

Comment: @PeterDuniho not sure how stating the facts of the feature design is considered hand wavy.

Comment: @JaredPar thanks for the insights here; personally I would support more emitting of warnings even when it didn't do so previously, but I understand the language team's constraints. Have you ever considered a "whinge about everything mode" (possibly on by default), vs "legacy stoic mode" (elective)? maybe `csc /stiffUpperLip`

Comment: "Hand-wavy" in the sense that it doesn't seem to address the thinking _behind_ the design. I see `var` as a "wildcard" only the sense that it matches compile-time type of an expression. I don't see any good reason that it should treat `null` differently. All your answer does is confirm the behavior was intended. It doesn't really explain _why_ that behavior is intended, nor how it benefits programmers.

Comment: After studying the output of the compiler for a while I go this: `var` cases don't check the type, only doing any "when" checks. For type safety in those checks and inside the case the type is resolved using "var type resolution". So `var x when...` is effectively saying I only care about the when side. So if there is no `when` then follows that it becomes the default. There is logic here, just needs to be documented!

Comment: @MarcGravell we have a feature called warning waves that's meant to make it easier, less compat breaky, to introduce new warnings.  Essentially every compiler release is a new wave and you can opt into the warnings via /wave:1, /wave:2, /wave:all.

Comment: @JaredPar (goes to look how to opt in to that in "dotnet build")

Comment: @MarcGravell Also, you could write a Roslyn analyzer and fix for this relatively simply.

Comment: This gist demonstrates that `null` is typeless: https://gist.github.com/jcdickinson/e3a884eb4ee3e23f5ab7f825766ebb92

Comment: @JonathanDickinson I don't think that shows what you think it shows. That just shows a `null` is a valid `string` reference, and any `string` reference (including `null`) can be implicitly cast (reference-preserving) to an `object` reference, and any `object` reference that is `null` can be successfully upcast (explicit) to any other type, still being `null`. Not really the same thing in terms of the compiler type system.

Comment: @JaredPar you say that default will never be hit even for a bool value that isn't 1 or 0, but I've demonstrated otherwise: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/544#issuecomment-300179855

Answer (score 22):

I'm putting together multiple twitter comments here - this is actually new to me, and I'm hoping that jaredpar will jump in with a more comprehensive answer, but; short version as I understand it:

```
case string s:
```

is interpreted as `if(someString is string) { s = (string)someString; ...` or `if((s = (someString as string)) != null) { ... }` - either of which involves a `null` test - which is failed in your case; conversely:

```
case var o:
```

where the compiler resolves `o` as `string` is simply `o = (string)someString; ...` - no `null` test, **despite** the fact that it looks similar on the surface, just with the compiler providing the type.

finally:

```
default:
```

here *cannot be reached*, because the case above catches everything. This may be a compiler bug in that it didn't emit an unreachable code warning.

I agree that this is *very* subtle and nuanced, and confusing. But apparently the `case var o` scenario has uses with null propagation (`o?.Length ?? 0` etc). I agree that it is odd that this works so *very* differently between `var o` and `string s`, but it is what the compiler currently does.

Answer (score 14):

It's because `case <Type>` matches on the **dynamic** (run-time) type, not the static (compile-time) type. `null` doesn't have a dynamic type, so it can't match against `string`. `var` is just the fallback.

*(Posting because I like short answers.)*